# Unity2D - how to move object to the touched position

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm using my android device to detect the touched position and move my object, but my object change the position way to far it disapears from my camera view, do I need to use ScreenToWorldPoint? It so, how do I use it?

**Here is my code:**

```
void Update() {
    for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            transform.position = new Vector3 (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x, Input.GetTouch(i).position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need `ScreenToWorldPoint. Input.touch returns position on screen so you need to convert this position to fit you world space.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
private void Update()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            var worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
            transform.position = worldPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SelectObject : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    GameObject hitObj;
    RaycastHit hit;
    private float speed = 1;

    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
            switch (touch.phase) {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (touch.position);
                    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 10)) {
                            hitObj = hit.collider.gameObject;
                    }
                    break;
            case TouchPhase.Moved:

                // If the finger is on the screen, move the object smoothly to the touch position          
                float step = speed * Time.deltaTime; // calculate distance to move
                if(hitObj != null)
                    hitObj.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3 (touch.position.x, touch.position.y, hitObj.transform.position.z));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```